# Can I use a keyword argument from another app to connect the URLs of two different aps together?

Tags: javascript, python, django, vue.js

I'm currently developing an application using the Django REST Framework and Vue in which people can monitor a device's signal outputs.

For some context, I created a custom user model with a unique UUID4 user ID that would be assigned to each user. This model is in a Django app that I called *accounts*. Similarly, I have the user's data recording sessions and associated data in separate models in an app that I call *studio*.

My problem is this: I realized I would like to associate the data collected to the user's account and whatever session they wish to tie this data to. However, since these models are in different Django apps, I am getting the error
`get() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user_id'` when I try to tie the URLs of the *account* and *studio* apps together. Relevant code snippets are below:

**models.py (in *studio*)**

```
from django.db import models


class Session(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(
        'accounts.CustomUser', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    session_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, blank=False)

    def get_associated_user_id(self):
        return (f'{self.user_id}')

    def __str__(self):
        return (f"Session ID: {self.session_id}")


class LaserData(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(
        'accounts.CustomUser', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    session_id = models.ForeignKey('Session', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    laser_current = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=3)
    laser_temperature = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=3)
    laser_temperature_set = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=3)
    tec_voltage_positive = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=3)
    tec_voltage_negative = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=3)
    tec_voltage_differential = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=8, decimal_places=3)
    ambient_temperature = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=3)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('timestamp',)

    def get_associated_user_id(self):
        return (f'{self.user_id}')

    def get_associated_session_id(self):
        return self.session_id

    def __str__(self):
        return (f"MicroModule data recorded at {self.timestamp}.")
```

**views.py (in *studio*)**

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http.response import Http404

from .models import Session, LaserData
from .serializers import SessionSerializer, LaserDataSerializer


class SessionListView(APIView):
    def get(self,  request, u_id, format=None):
        session = Session.objects.get(user_id=u_id)[0:9]
        serializer = SessionSerializer(session, many=True)

        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = SessionSerializer(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()

        return Response(serializer.data)


class SessionDetailView(APIView):
    def get_session(self, u_id, s_id):
        try:
            return Session.objects.filter(user_id=u_id).get(session_id=s_id)
        except Session.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def get(self, request, user_id, session_id, format=None):
        session = self.get_session(user_id, session_id)
        serializer = SessionSerializer(session)

        return Response(serializer.data)


class LaserDataListView(APIView):
    def get(self,  request, u_id, s_id, format=None):
        laser_data = LaserData.objects.get(
            user_id=u_id, session_id=s_id)[0:9]
        serializer = LaserDataSerializer(laser_data, many=True)

        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = LaserDataSerializer(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()

        return Response(serializer.data)


class LaserDatumDetailView(APIView):
    def get_datum(self, u_id, s_id, time):
        try:
            return LaserData.objects.get(
                user_id=u_id,
                session_id=s_id,
                timestamp=time
            )
        except LaserData.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def get(self, request, user_id, session_id, timestamp, format=None):
        laser_datum = self.get_datum(user_id, session_id, timestamp)
        serializer = LaserDataSerializer(laser_datum)

        return Response(serializer.data)
```

**urls.py (in *studio*)**

```
from django.urls import path, include

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path(r'sessions/', views.SessionListView.as_view()),
    path(r'sessions/<str:session_id>/',
         views.SessionDetailView.as_view()),
    path(r'sessions/<str:session_id>/laser-data/',
         views.LaserDataListView.as_view()),
    path(r'sessions/<str:session_id>/laser-data/<str:timestamp>/',
         views.LaserDatumDetailView.as_view()),
]
```

**models.py(in *accounts*)**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
)

import uuid


class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, username, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('User must have an email address.')

        custom_user = self.model(
            username=username,
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
        )

        custom_user.set_password(password)
        custom_user.save(using=self._db)

        return custom_user

    def create_staffuser(self, email, username, password):
        custom_staffuser = self.create_user(
            email,
            username,
            password=password,
        )

        custom_staffuser.staff = True

        custom_staffuser.save(using=self._db)

        return custom_staffuser

    def create_superuser(self, email, username, password):
        custom_superuser = self.create_user(
            email,
            username,
            password=password,
        )

        custom_superuser.staff = True
        custom_superuser.admin = True

        custom_superuser.save(using=self._db)

        return custom_superuser


class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    # Required Fields
    user_id = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True,
        default=uuid.uuid4,
        editable=False
    )
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True
    )
    username = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
        blank=False
    )

    # Optional Fields
    first_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        blank=True,
        default=''
    )
    last_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        blank=True,
        default=''
    )
    company_or_organization = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        blank=True,
        default=''
    )
    purpose = models.TextField(
        max_length=1000,
        blank=True,
        default=''
    )
    mm_serial_number = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        blank=True,
        default=''
    )

    # Status
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    # Staff Permissions
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['date_joined']

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def get_first_name(self):
        return self.first_name

    def get_last_name(self):
        return self.last_name

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, application_label):
        return True

    def __str__(self):
        return (f'{self.user_id}')

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.staff

    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        return self.admin
```

**views.py (in *accounts*)**

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import authentication, permissions, status

from django.http.response import Http404
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

from .serializers import CustomUserSerializer

import uuid

CustomUser = get_user_model()


class CustomUserListView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        custom_users = CustomUser.objects.all()
        serializer = CustomUserSerializer(custom_users, many=True)

        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = CustomUserSerializer(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()

            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


class CustomUserDetailView(APIView):
    def get_user(self, id):
        try:
            return CustomUser.objects.get(user_id=id)
        except CustomUser.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def get(self, request, user_id, format=None):
        custom_user = self.get_user(user_id)
        serializer = CustomUserSerializer(custom_user)

        return Response(serializer.data)

    def put(self, request, user_id):
        custom_user = self.get_user(user_id)
        serializer = CustomUserSerializer(custom_user, data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()

            return Response(serializer.data)

        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**urls.py (in *accounts*)**

```
from django.urls import path, include

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path(r'accounts/', views.CustomUserListView.as_view()),
    path(r'accounts/<uuid:user_id>/',
         views.CustomUserDetailView.as_view(), name='my-account'),
    path(r'accounts/<uuid:user_id>/', include('studio.urls')),
]
```

This is my first time writing a web application of any sort so please don't flame me too much. I would appreciate any help on my main problem as well as any pointers/tips for best practice in web application development.

Thank you all in advance!